# How to make custom Tuple class generic?

Tags: java, generics, hashcode

I'm trying to make a generic tuple class. It stores its elements as an ArrayList. Of course, this class should override hashcode and equals methods.

How could I make hashcode method for this class? You see, in the code, I am having trouble.

Also, for the equals method, why does the compiler force me to use the '?'. Why couldn't I just use the T?

```
public static class Tuple<T> { 
        ArrayList<T> tuple = new ArrayList<>();

        public Tuple(ArrayList<T> items) {
            for (T item : items) {
                tuple.add(item);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            T sum = ???;
            for (T item : tuple) {
                sum += item.hashCode();
            }
            return sum;
        }

        @Override 
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof Tuple<?>) {
                Tuple<?> tup= (Tuple<?>) o;
                if (tup.tuple.size() != this.tuple.size()) {
                    return false;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < this.tuple.size(); i++) {
                    if (this.tuple.get(i) != tup.tuple.get(i)) {
                        return false;
                    } 
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just delegate to using the `ArrayList`'s `hashCode` and `equals`? It would be much simpler.

Comment: There is no reason, thank you!

Comment: The reason for the '?' is because you cannot be sure that the other Tuple that you are comparing to, has the same member type.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, we should delegate the `hashCode` and the `equals` methods to the `ArrayList<T> tuple` instance variable. For the `hashCode` it's trivial. For the `equals` it's just a little more complicated than that because we don't want our custom `Tuple` to be equals with an `ArrayList`. So here it is:

```
public class Tuple<T> {

     // I made this private because I'm pedantic ;)
     private final ArrayList<T> tuple = new ArrayList<>();

     // this does the same as your code, it's just easier to read
     public Tuple(ArrayList<T> items) {
         tuple.addAll(items);
     }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return tuple.hashCode();
    }

    // generated by eclipse
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Tuple other = (Tuple) obj;
        if (tuple == null) {
            if (other.tuple != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!tuple.equals(other.tuple))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you want to deal with the case when the `tuple` can be null, then you can use a slightly more complex `hashCode`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((tuple == null) ? 0 : tuple.hashCode());
    return tuple.hashCode();
}
```

In general, I don't like to write these methods myself. Usually, I make my IDE to generate the stuff. All I need to take care of is to re-generate it when I add new fields. Apache [`HashCodeBuilder`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) and [`EqualsBuilder`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) are also great alternatives.

Comment: "pedantic" (I'm more, apparently)